# Nullable <= vs == comparison result

Tags: c#, comparison, operator-keyword, nullable

This behaviour sounds to be wrong to me.

```
DateTime? birth = null;
DateTime? death = null;

Console.WriteLine(birth == death); // true
Console.WriteLine(birth <= death); // false
```

Why is it so? This is incredibly strange. Of course I mean why the second expression does not evaluate to `true` as well.

EDIT:

I understand that the following comparisons return `false`, because it cannot be said how they relate to each other:

```
Console.WriteLine(birth < death); // false
Console.WriteLine(birth > death); // false
```

This is perfectly understandable behaviour. But... look at the logic:

- `<=` means `<` or `==`
- we don't know how to read `<` - it could be `true` or `false`
- we do know that `==` is `true`
- since one of the conditions is `true`, the other condition cannot *untrue* the result. This is logic **or**, not **and**.

My point is that **`true or something else`** should be true.

I know the C# team designed it that way, but my intuition is different. Since smart people have written C# with such rules, I just want to learn ***why*** my intuition is wrong here :)

Comment: Are you asking why the language is designed this way, or wanting proof that the behaviour you're seeing is compliant with the language?

Comment: @JonSkeet Why the language is designed this way :) I just don't understand the reason to make it behave this way...

Comment: false in this case means 'unknown'. The designers could have implemented the comparison operators (excluding == and !=) so that they return a nullable boolean result instead of a boolean but readability in the code using them would have been clearly impacted. I guess they preferred to implement it this way although there might be corner cases which are clearly documented.

Comment: @vc74 please see the edit :)

Comment: @Randolph birth < death or birth > death returns false because one of the variables is null. The result would be false with 'birth = DateTime.Now'

Comment: @Randolph '<= means < or ==', no, not in the case of nullables. x <= y is equivalent to (x.HasValue && y.HasValue && (x.Value <= y.Value)) in such a case.

Comment: @vc74 but the only thing that matters is that birth == death is true, therefore birth <= death should also be true. I know how it works like and what the standard is, I just don't understand the reasoning standing behind this...

Comment: @Randolph I understand your not looking for specs but for an explanation of the way it was designed. But like I said a way to remove the ambiguity could have been to let these operators return a bool? value instead of a bool value. But if the designers had made this choice, the code would look like:    bool? comparison = birth <= death; if (comparison.HasValue && comparison.Value)        which is a bit cumbersome

Comment: @vc74 OK, this makes sense. Please write this as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: @Randolph Now I'm wondering why the C# compiler reproduces the Nullable class behavior rather than use it...

Comment: @vc74 it may be a CLR thing, not C#

Comment: @Randolph This IL code has definitely been produced by the c# compiler, I'm just surprised it knows about Nulable<T> but not about Nullable.

Comment: @vc74 Nullable is a static class with static methods, maybe that's the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your not looking for specs but for an explanation of why nullables were designed this way.

To remove the ambiguity, the designers could have let these operators return a `bool?` value instead of a `bool` value which would be null in case one of the operands is null.

But if they had made this choice, the code would look like:

```
bool? comparison = birth <= death; 
if (comparison.HasValue && comparison.Value)
{
}
```

which is a bit cumbersome.

As a side note, it seems like, looking at the IL, the C# compiler generates the comparison with default values first and then checks if one of the operands is null which seems a bit odd...

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .locals init ([0] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32> x,
           [1] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32> V_1,
           [2] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32> V_2)
  IL_0000:  ldloca.s   x
  IL_0002:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0003:  call       instance void valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::.ctor(!0)
  IL_0008:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_0009:  newobj     instance void valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::.ctor(!0)
  IL_000e:  ldloc.0
  IL_000f:  stloc.1
  IL_0010:  stloc.2
  IL_0011:  ldloca.s   V_1
  IL_0013:  call       instance !0 valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::GetValueOrDefault()
  IL_0018:  ldloca.s   V_2
  IL_001a:  call       instance !0 valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::GetValueOrDefault()
  IL_001f:  ble.s      IL_0024
  IL_0021:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0022:  br.s       IL_0033
  IL_0024:  ldloca.s   V_1
  IL_0026:  call       instance bool valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::get_HasValue()
  IL_002b:  ldloca.s   V_2
  IL_002d:  call       instance bool valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::get_HasValue()
  IL_0032:  and
  IL_0033:  brfalse.s  IL_003a
  IL_0035:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine()
  IL_003a:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

It is also the replicating the logic already present in the static [Nullable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Answer (score 4):

According to ECMA-334 standard (**8.19 Nullable types**) (emphasis mine):

> A comparison operator (`==`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`) has a lifted form when the operand types are both non-nullable value types and the result type is 
>   `bool`. The lifted form of a comparison operator is formed by adding a 
>   `?` modifier to each operand type (but not to the result type). Lifted forms of the `==`
>    and `!=`
>    operators consider two null values equal, and a null value unequal to a non-null value. Lifted forms of the `<`, `>`, `<=`, and `>=`
>    operators **return false if one or both operands are null**.